# How to draw a circle which should be clipped only within the diagonal line in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to draw a circle which is clipped by a diagonal line. Here is my non-working code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the circle with radius 6
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 6, color='r', fill=False)

# Set up the plot (reuse the previous grid settings)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.grid()

# Add the circle to the plot
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(circle)

# Draw a diagonal line
plt.plot([0, 7], [7, 0], color='b', linestyle='--')

# Set aspect ratio to ensure square grid cells
ax.set_aspect("equal")

# Clip the circle using the diagonal line.
# This doesn't work
ax.set_clip_path(plt.Polygon([[0, 0], [7, 0], [0, 7]]))

# Show the plot
plt.title("Circle Centered at (0,0) (not) Clipped by Diagonal Line")
plt.show()
```

Here is what it shows currently.

[image]

I don't want to show any of the circle that goes past the diagonal line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `transform` when creating a polygon, and clip the circle with `circle.set_clip_path(polygon)`. An example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the circle with radius 6
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 6, color='r', fill=False)

# Set up the plot (reuse the previous grid settings)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.grid()

# Add the circle to the plot
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(circle)

# Draw a diagonal line
plt.plot([0, 7], [7, 0], color='b', linestyle='--')

# Set aspect ratio to ensure square grid cells
ax.set_aspect("equal")

polygon = plt.Polygon([[0, 0], [7, 0], [0, 7]], transform=ax.transData)

# Clip the circle using the diagonal line.
circle.set_clip_path(polygon)

# Show the plot
plt.title("Circle Centered at (0,0) Clipped by Diagonal Line")
plt.show()
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea about transdata.

Comment: If I only want the part of the diagonal line between the two points where it intersects the circle, is that doable easily?  Essentially I want to truncate the circle with the diagonal line.

Comment: I'll ask another question

Comment: Yes, it should be easy. Please, refer to my answer there.

Answer (score 3):

If, rather than clipping a circle, you're willing to do some maths to find the points that the line intersects the circle and draw an [`Arc`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html#matplotlib.patches.Arc) instead, you could do:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Arc

# circle with radius 6
r = 6
origin = (0, 0)

# Set up the plot (reuse the previous grid settings)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 8))
ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
ax.set_ylim(0, 10)

# define line cutting through circle (y = mx + c)
m = -1
c = 7

def line(x, m, c):
    return m * np.asarray(x) + c

# get intersection points (using y^2 = r^2 - x^2 for the circle, substituting in
# the equation for the line and solving for x)
a = (m**2 + 1)
b = 2 * m * c
cq = c**2 - r**2

xs = np.sort(np.roots([a, b, cq]))
ys = line(xs, m, c)

# get end point angles of the arc
angles = np.rad2deg(np.arctan2(ys, xs))

arc = Arc(origin, r * 2, r * 2, theta1=angles[0], theta2=angles[1], color="b", lw=2)

# Add the arc to the plot
ax.add_patch(arc)

# Draw a diagonal line
ax.plot([0, 7], line([0, 7], m, c), color='b', linestyle='--')

# Set aspect ratio to ensure square grid cells
ax.set_aspect("equal")

# Show the plot
ax.set_title("Arc of circle Centered at (0,0)")
```

[image]

Comment: I want the opposite of this, sorry it wasn't clear. I want to see the circle while it is closer to the origin than the diagonal and the diagonal where the circle is further from the origin that the diagonal.

Comment: Ah, ok. The angles can just be flipped round then. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think it can't be done with clipping?

Comment: I would have thought that you could. Maybe you need the `Circle` patch to be in a `PatchCollection`, which has a [`set_clip_path`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection.set_clip_path) method

Comment: @Ratislaus beat me to the correct answer!