# How to remove "exterior" parts of a diagonal line that is clipping a circle

Tags: python, matplotlib

In this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78120592/1473517) it shown how to use [transdata](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/artists/transforms_tutorial.html) to clip a circle with a diagonal line. The code and images are:

```
 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the circle with radius 6
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 6, color='r', fill=False)

# Set up the plot (reuse the previous grid settings)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.grid()

# Add the circle to the plot
ax = plt.gca()
ax.add_patch(circle)

# Draw a diagonal line
plt.plot([0, 7], [7, 0], color='b', linestyle='--')

# Set aspect ratio to ensure square grid cells
ax.set_aspect("equal")

polygon = plt.Polygon([[0, 0], [7, 0], [0, 7]], transform=ax.transData)

# Clip the circle using the diagonal line.
circle.set_clip_path(polygon)

# Show the plot
plt.title("Circle Centered at (0,0) Clipped by Diagonal Line")
plt.show()
```

[image]

I would like the same image but with the part of the diagonal line outside the circle remmove. So all that is left is the truncate circular arc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the triangular polygon slightly bigger, style it appropriately, and add the respective patch to the plot instead of drawing a special diagonal line. Then you could add the circle, clip it using the polygon, and finally clip the polygon too, using the circle:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create the circle with radius 6
circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 6, color='r', fill=False)

# Set up the plot (reuse the previous grid settings)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.grid()

# Add the circle to the plot
ax = plt.gca()


# Set aspect ratio to ensure square grid cells
ax.set_aspect("equal")

# Make a polygon looking like a diagonal line on the visible part of the plot
polygon = plt.Polygon([[-1, -1], [7, 0], [0, 7]], transform=ax.transData, edgecolor='b', facecolor='w', linestyle='--')

# Add the polygon and circle to the plot
ax.add_patch(polygon)
ax.add_patch(circle)

# Clip the circle using the polygon appearing as a "diagonal line"
circle.set_clip_path(polygon)

# Clip the polygon ("exterior parts of the diagonal line") using the circle
polygon.set_clip_path(circle)

# Show the plot
plt.title("Circle Centered at (0,0) Clipped by Diagonal Line")
plt.show()
```

The output:
[image]